# Cut something/Cut at something

Tags: meaning, phrases

**It was as though freezing water was rising in his chest, cutting at his insides.**

What is the difference between "cut one's insides" and "cut **at** one's insides"?

Comment: It's a meaningless "stylistic choice" whether to use any preposition at all in your cited context. There are plenty of written instances of [***cut my insides***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cut+my+insides%22) in Google Books with no preposition. But there are plenty of [*cut **through** my insides*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cut+through+my+insides%22) and [*cut **at** my insides*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cut+at+my+insides%22), and I'm sure there will be other prepositions (there's at least one instances of *cut **to** my insides* in GB).

Comment: ...in short, the choice of preposition (including "none") doesn't really "mean" anything here, and it would be pedantic to suggest any particular form is more "correct" than others.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between "cut one's insides" and "cut at one's insides"?

In "cut one's insides" "**insides**" is a noun and the object of "cut", i.e. the **insides** receive the action of cutting.

E.g. "The blade of the knife cut my finger."

"**at one's insides**" is an adverbial modifier. It indicates continuous or continual attempts to cut in the direction of (or to) the insides - the context will say how successfully.

E.g. "He **cut at the rope** with his knife but the blade was blunt and he made little impression." "He **cut at the rope** and quickly severed it."

It is worth noting that "to cut", in the example, is used figuratively = "to inflict pain as if by a knife."

Comment: Nice description of the distinction between a completed action and an attempted action, successful or not